# Ruby on Rails running in IIS 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iis, iis-10

is there a way to run Ruby on Rails using IIS version 10+? There are a few resources that suggest using HttpPlatformHandler but I believe that is no longer a plugin for IIS. Is there any way to do it? I have to run a rails app on IIS.

Comment: From where did you see that it is no longer a plugin for IIS?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105 & https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164

Comment: That's for ASP.NET Core only, as HttpPlatformHandler cannot meet its unique needs. Hope you pay attention to the context, as HttpPlatformHandler is still the way to go for Java/Ruby and so on.

Comment: @LexLi in the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, the configuration editor will throw errors for anyone trying to create a Web.config file for their ruby app. HttpPlatformHandler will not install on a machine running IIS v10 and reports an error that "IIS must be version 8 or higher", and does not recognize that IIS is running v10

Comment: @aronlmin that’s because you are trying to install a very old version, https://blogs.iis.net/iisoobs

Comment: just in case, the right way to do things properly : https://www.hanselman.com/blog/announcing-running-ruby-on-rails-on-iis8-or-anything-else-really-with-the-new-httpplatformhandler